# Sorting and subscribing a Knockout observable array at the same time

Tags: sorting, knockout.js, subscribe

I'm trying to sort and subscribe to a observable array. I can't get both to work at the same time. I think it has to do the type of array. I have two arrays named "AttendanceArray" one is commented out. The active array allows clicking a checkbox which tracks the record using the subscribe method. With this array the column links do not work. If you reverse which array is commented then the sorting will work. I'm trying to get both features working at the same time.

```
AttendanceArray: ko.observableArray([
    new rosterItem(101, "J", "Smith", "RN Staff Nurse", false),
    new rosterItem(102, "T", "Davis", "LPN Staff Nurse", true),
    new rosterItem(103, "M", "Glass", "Resident Assistance", false),
    new rosterItem(104, "D", "Black", "Practioner", true)
    ]),

/*
    AttendanceArray: ko.observableArray([
    {ID: 101, FirstName: "J", LastName: "Smith", Title: "RN Staff Nurse", Present: false},
    {ID: 102, FirstName: "T", LastName: "Davis", Title: "LPN Staff Nurse", Present: true},
    {ID: 103, FirstName: "M", LastName: "Glass", Title: "Resident Assistance", Present: false},
    {ID: 104, FirstName: "D", LastName: "Black", Title: "Practioner", Present: true}
    ]),
    */
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jjfrick/0ykasv4b/63/

Answer (score 3):

The sorting in the implementation using the `rosterItem` instances had some issues in the comparison of observables and non-observables.

In the *(runnable)* example below the main changes include

- changed the viewmodels `FirstName`, `LastName` and `Title` to non-observables.
- use parenthesis to compare on `Present` as it is an observable

  ```
  if (a.Present() === b.Present())
  ```

```js
var rosterItem = function (id, firstName, lastName, title, present) {
    
    this.ID = ko.observable(id);
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName = lastName;
    this.Title = title;
    this.Present = ko.observable(present);
    this.PresentOriginal = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.Present);

    // Subscribe when checked changes and push or remove items
    this.Present.subscribe(function () {
        if (this.Present() != this.PresentOriginal) {
            viewModel.changedAttendance.push(this);
        }
        else {
            viewModel.changedAttendance.remove(this);
        }
    }.bind(this));
};

var viewModel = {

    AttendanceArray: ko.observableArray([
        new rosterItem(101, "J", "Smith", "RN Staff Nurse", false),
        new rosterItem(102, "T", "Davis", "LPN Staff Nurse", true),
        new rosterItem(103, "M", "Glass", "Resident Assistance", false),
        new rosterItem(104, "D", "Black", "Practioner", true)
        ]),


    changedAttendance: ko.observableArray([]),
    selectedSortBy: ko.observable("Present"),
}
viewModel.setSortOrder = function (item) {
    switch (item) {
        case 'FirstName':
            this.selectedSortBy('FirstName');         
            break;
        case 'LastName':
            this.selectedSortBy('LastName');
            break;
        case 'Title':
            this.selectedSortBy('Title');
            break;
        case 'Present':
            this.selectedSortBy('Present');
            break;
    }
}.bind(viewModel);

viewModel.sortByTitle = function (a, b) {  // sort by ListOrder column
    if (a.Title === b.Title) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (a.Title < b.Title) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}.bind(viewModel);

viewModel.sortByPresent = function (a, b) {  // sort by ListOrder column
            
    if (a.Present() === b.Present()) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a.Present() > b.Present()) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}.bind(viewModel);

viewModel.sortByFirstName = function (a, b) {  // sort by ListOrder column

    if (a.FirstName === b.FirstName) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a.FirstName < b.FirstName) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}.bind(viewModel);

viewModel.sortByLastName = function (a, b) {  // sort by ListOrder column
    
    if (a.LastName === b.LastName) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a.LastName < b.LastName) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}.bind(viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
#list_wrapper {
    width: 500px;
}

ul.multiple_columns li {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

        <div class="tableView">
            <div id="list_wrapper">
                <ul class="multiple_columns">
                    <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: function () { $root.setSortOrder('FirstName') }">FirstName</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: function () { $root.setSortOrder('LastName') }">LastName</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: function () { $root.setSortOrder('Title') }">Title</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: function () { $root.setSortOrder('Present') }">Present</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
 

            <!-- ko if: $root.selectedSortBy() === 'FirstName' -->
                <div data-bind="template: { name: 'AttendanceList', foreach: $root.AttendanceArray().sort($root.sortByFirstName) }"></div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: $root.selectedSortBy() === 'LastName' -->
                <div data-bind="template: { name: 'AttendanceList', foreach: $root.AttendanceArray().sort($root.sortByLastName) }"></div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: $root.selectedSortBy() === 'Title' -->
                <div data-bind="template: { name: 'AttendanceList', foreach: $root.AttendanceArray().sort($root.sortByTitle) }"></div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: $root.selectedSortBy() === 'Present' -->
                <div data-bind="template: { name: 'AttendanceList', foreach: $root.AttendanceArray().sort($root.sortByPresent) }"></div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="changedList">
        Changed List to Send to server: ( Count: <span data-bind="text: changedAttendance().length"></span> )
        <ul data-bind=" template : { name : 'changedAttendanceTemplate', foreach: changedAttendance }"></ul>
    </div>
 </script>

<script id="AttendanceList" type="text/html">
    <div id="list_wrapper">
        <ul class="multiple_columns">
            <li data-bind="text: FirstName"></li>
            <li data-bind="text: LastName"></li>
            <li data-bind="text: Title"></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Present" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</script>
<script id="changedAttendanceTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: ID"/>
    </li>
</script>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you pfx! This was driving me nuts.